# php 7.1 update breaks pdo cli

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, shell, pdo

After an update of php 7.1(`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful main`) some extensions are missing in the PHP cli.
FPM extensions:

```
array:49 [▼
  0 => "Core"
  1 => "date"
  2 => "libxml"
  3 => "openssl"
  4 => "pcre"
  5 => "zlib"
  6 => "filter"
  7 => "hash"
  8 => "Reflection"
  9 => "SPL"
  10 => "session"
  11 => "standard"
  12 => "cgi-fcgi"
  13 => "PDO"
  14 => "xml"
  15 => "calendar"
  16 => "ctype"
  17 => "curl"
  18 => "dom"
  19 => "mbstring"
  20 => "fileinfo"
  21 => "ftp"
  22 => "gd"
  23 => "gettext"
  24 => "iconv"
  25 => "json"
  26 => "exif"
  27 => "mcrypt"
  28 => "pdo_pgsql"
  29 => "pgsql"
  30 => "Phar"
  31 => "posix"
  32 => "pspell"
  33 => "readline"
  34 => "recode"
  35 => "shmop"
  36 => "SimpleXML"
  37 => "soap"
  38 => "sockets"
  39 => "sysvmsg"
  40 => "sysvsem"
  41 => "sysvshm"
  42 => "tokenizer"
  43 => "wddx"
  44 => "xmlreader"
  45 => "xmlwriter"
  46 => "xsl"
  47 => "zip"
  48 => "Zend OPcache"
]
```

CLI extensions:

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

FPM is working fine but PHP commands are broken.
I am trying to call a command that worked fine before, but I get this exception:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
could not find driver (SQL: select * from "schools")
```

Why is the `pdo_pgsql` extension disabled in CLI? I didn't change the configuration. I only did an update.

Comment: FPM and CLI have different php.ini files. Have you checked if pdo_pgsql is enabled in the CLI of php.ini?

Comment: @Niels There both not enabled in the `php.ini`. All extensions I installed automatically where enabled. Maybe this has been disabled by the update, I will try to enable pgsql by the `php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue... The update for some reason also installed PHP 7.2 and used it for the CLI while FPM was still 7.1.

I removed php 7.2 and it worked. Installing `php7.2-pgsql` would also work.